# SQL statement to output record of person that has more than x counts of a condition

Tags: sql

I am a beginner in SQL and I need help to get the solution for this condition.
I want Output as a name of any person who managed to ride the Super Rollercoaster more than 50 times on a single day.

```
create table visitor( 
    visitID         char(n),
    name            char(n) not null,
    primary key (visitID)
);

create table ticket(
    ticketID        char(n),
    ticketType      char(n),
    day             int(n),
    month           char(n),
    year            int(n),
    seasonID        char(n),
    visitID         char(n),
    primary key (ticketID), 
    foreign key (seasonID) references seasonPerClass, 
    foreign key (visitID) references visitor
);

create table attractionVisit(
    attractionID        char(n),
    ticketID        char(n),
    foreign key (attractionID) references attraction, 
    foreign key (ticketID) references ticket
);

create table attraction(
    attractionID        char(n),
    attractionName  char(n) not null,
    primary key (attractionID)
);
```

I am unable to test my code, but so far I have

```
SELECT 
    distinct Name
FROM 
    attractionVisit 
        Natural Join 
    ticket 
        Natural Join 
    visitor 
        Natural Join 
    attraction group by VisitID, day   
WHERE 
    attractionName = ‘Super Rollercoaster’ having count(*) > 50;
```

I don't know if this is right or not. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHERE should be put before GROUP BY

```
SELECT 
    distinct Name
FROM 
    attractionVisit 
    Natural Join 
    ticket 
    Natural Join 
    visitor Natural 
    Join attraction 
WHERE 
    attractionName = 'Super Rollercoaster'
group by 
    VisitID, day   
having 
    count(*) > 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    distinct(v.Name)
FROM 
    attractionVisit av 
    inner Join attraction a 
        on av.attractionID=attractionID
    inner join ticket t 
        on av.ticketID=t.ticketID
    inner join visitor v 
        on t.visitID=v.visitID   
WHERE 
    attractionName = ‘Super Rollercoaster’ 
group by 
    v.name, t.day
having 
    count(*) > 50;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    Name
FROM 
    (
        select 
            distinct name,
            count(name) as Name_Count 
        from 
            attractionVisit 
            Natural Join 
            ticket 
            Natural Join 
            visitor 
            Natural Join 
            attraction 
        group by 
            VisitID, day   
        WHERE 
            attractionName = ‘Super Rollercoaster’ 
    ) 
where 
    Name_Count >50;
```

At present I don't have sql to work with. I answered by my experience. I too had faced the same before. May b I remember my answer.

Comment: There are two queries. The outer one and the nested one. The first Where Clause is for the inner query and the 2nd one is for the outer query. I have used braces if you can observe and two select statements. @Leptonator